# Table Joining (ms Access, sql)

Tags: ms-access

Hoping I’ve not over simplified things,

I have 2 tables: tblTestA and tblTestB

[image]

Both tables are linked through their common ID fields.
I’m looking to select all records from tblTestA that have a date greater than #2013/01/01# its Date field.
Then, from this record set, further filter by keeping only those records who have at least 1 non-Null value in Field1 or Field2 from tblTest2 (i.e. remove double Nulls)

Is there a way to modify the following unworkable/pseudo code so that the above is achieved?

```
SELECT tblTestA.ID, tblTestB.Field1, tblTestB.Field2
FROM tblTestA
WHERE  tblTestA.Date > #2013/01/01#
Inner Join tblTestB
On  tblTestA.ID= tblTestB.ID
Where (Not IsNull(tblTestB.Field1)) Or (Not IsNull(tblTestB.Field2));
```

In the real scenario (due to the way the tables are structured, their size, and additional factors) querying only on the non-Null requirement takes very long. Querying only on the date greater than #2013/01/01# requirement takes very little time. So I’m thinking that if we can return the smaller date requirement result set and then use the common ID field to do the second filter on the non-Null check, then, the whole query might complete faster.

**Edit:**
Modifying the above to...

```
SELECT tblTestA.ID, tblTestB.Field1, tblTestB.Field2
FROM tblTestA
Inner Join tblTestB
On  tblTestA.ID= tblTestB.ID
WHERE  tblTestA.Date > #2013/01/01#
AND
(Not tblTestB.Field1 Is Not Null) Or (tblTestB.Field2 Is Not Null);
```

...returns records that are within the required date range but seems to also link the non-Null filter to that same date range. Entries for Field1 and Field2 may have been entered before the date range requirement filter. I've probably over simplified things from the real scenario, but I'm looking to do 2 things: 1. return records within a date range, and 2. from this result set, filter out any records that do not have at least one non-Null value in Field1 or Field2 *from any date range*.

Comment: Use just one `WHERE` clause (and put it after the join): `Where tblTestA.Date > #2013/01/01# AND (tblTestB.Field1 Is Not Null OR tblTestB.Field2 Is Not Null);`

Comment: Many thanks HansUp, I've added an edit to the main question. I can try to further expand things if information is too limited.

Comment: `tblTestB.Field1 Is Not Null` means just what it says.  `Not tblTestB.Field1 Is Not Null` will be True when `tblTestB.Field1 Is Null`. That is `Not Not` the `WHERE` clause I suggested.

Comment: Changed "also link the non-Null requirement" to "also link the non-Null filter" in last paragraph to correct sentence interpretation. The code works, it's just that in the real scenario, this code also seems to link the date the result was entered into Field1 or Field2 to the same date range filter in the first part of the query, which is not what we want. Field1/2 entries may have occurred outside the date range filter. We need the field1/2 entries to be date-independent. In the real query, additional fields are accessed in tblTestA/B equivalents. I've probably over simplified here.

Comment: No probs, I'll get back when I better understand the problem and am better equipped to translate. Many thanks again for your time.

Comment: Ah the `Nulls` truly NULL or are they zero length strings?